# Insert function insde body tag

Tags: functions

How to insert this function inside `<body>`

```
<?php function Ciusan_NBar(){ global $options; $options = get_option('Ciusan_NBar');
    if($options['CNB_Showing']=='yes'){ ?>
    <div class="Ciusan_NBar" style=" <?php if($options[CNB_FixedBar]=='yes'){echo 'position: fixed;';}elseif($options[CNB_FixedBar] == 'no'){echo 'position: absolute;'; } ?>!important;">
        <input id="hide" type="radio" name="bar" value="hide">
        <input id="show" type="radio" name="bar" value="show" checked="checked">

        <label for="hide">hide</label>
        <label for="show">show</label>

        <div class="Ciusan_NText"><?php echo $options['CNB_Content']; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php }} ?>
```

**EDITED:**

I'm not want insert on `wp_head` or `wp_footer` but i want this function auto insert after `<body>` tag.

```
<html>
<head></head>    
<body>
    <?php echo Ciusan_NBar(); ?>
    blah...
    blah...
    blah...
    blah...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where inside the body? Just before the closing tag, just after the opening tag or anywhere?

Comment: Just add that code in your functions.php and then add `Ciusan_NBar()` in your template files where needed. You can also hook your function to a specific filter if you need to add the code to something specific like before the loop you would use `loop_start` hook. If you are going to hook your function, then you should `return` your content, not `echo` it

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends" as usual :)

You can do it with hooks and I would recommand [action-hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in this case or you can do it on your own.

**In both cases** : define your function in a plugin, `functions.php` could be fine but be sure your function is not critical and can be dropped when you change theme.

**If you do not want to use action-hooks** be sure to test if function exists before using it in a template :

```
if( function_exists('Ciusan_NBar') ){
    Ciusan_NBar();
}
```

Regarding the function declaration I would recommand you some [coding standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/), for example :

```
if( 'yes' === $options['CNB_Showing'] )
```

It's better to put variable to the right in case you omit an equal sign.